# Is it possible to backup and restore a Netbackup Master server using Windows Server Backup?

Tags: windows-server-2019, disaster-recovery, windows-server-backup, netbackup, veritas

I have installed Netbackup 8.2 master server on Windows Server 2019 system.
I read this [document](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100043701) , which says you neet to re-install OS and Netbackup itself, then the catalog in order to restore NetBackup Master Server. I wonder if its possible to do the same thing using Windows Server Backup. Actually I tried to restore Netbackup Master Server from an backup image taken with Windows Server Backup and it worked fine. Do you need to re-install everything from the OS, to restore an Master Server?